# Translation issue with admin-on-rest FormTab

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I've got a translation issue on admin-on-rest. My tabs have labels when FormTab are directly inside the Edit component.

The tab title is empty for the third one only. I've got an error (MyCustomFormTab) :

> Warning: Missing translation for key: "undefined"

```
const EditComponent = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <TabbedForm>
            <FormTab label="tab Title" />
            <FormTab label="Other Tab Title" />
            <MyCustomFormTab />
        </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
)

const MyCustomFormtab = props => (
    <FormTab label="My Custom tab Title" />
)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormTab` components must be direct children of the `TabbedForm` component.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Isn't it possible to bypass it ? I've split my TabbedForm for maintainability because it's a huge one.